# error: macro names must be identifiers

Tags: c++, macros

I keep getting the error "macro names must be identifiers" in the following code, and I'm not sure why. I haven't violated any of the naming standards as far as I know. This is from my "dllist.h" file:

```
#ifndef _DOUBLY_LINKED_LIST_
#define _DOUBLY_LINKED_LIST_

template <class T>
class IntDLLNode {

friend class IntDLList;
 
    public:

        IntDLLNode() {next = prev = NULL;}

        IntDLLNode(const T& el, IntDLLNode *n = NULL, IntDLLNode *p = NULL) {
        info = el;
        next = n;
        prev = p;
        }

protected:

        T info;
        IntDLLNode<T> *next, *prev;
};

template <class T>
class IntDLList {

    public:

    IntDLList() {head = tail = NULL;}

    void addToDLLTail(const T& el);
    void addToDLLHead(const T& el);
    T deleteFromDLLTail();
    T deleteFromDLLHead();
    void deleteNode(int);
    void isInList(int) const;
    void addSorted(int);
    void printList();

private:

    IntDLLNode<T> *head, *tail;
};

#endif
```

I've also tried names like DOUBLY_LINKED_LIST and DOUBLYLINKEDLIST -- all result in the same error.

Comment: On which line are you getting the error?  (I am unable to duplicate your error with the code you posted)

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from this header and not a source file that includes this header?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Voting to close, OP has admitted in comments to one of the answers that the problem was caused by some invisible character in macro name.

Answer (score 2):

You are violating a rule. `_DOUBLY_LINKED_LIST_` is an invalid identifier. Anything that starts with an underscore, immediately followed by an upper-case character is reserved for the implementation.

Try `DOUBLY_LINKED_LIST`.

Also try to `#include <cstddef>` for `NULL`. Or use `0`. Or better yet, if you have C++11 support, use `std::nullptr`.

Comment: "I've also tried names like DOUBLY_LINKED_LIST and DOUBLYLINKEDLIST -- all result in the same error."

Comment: @user1890265 That's not possible. Have you saved the file before you recompiled?

Comment: @user1890265 can you `#include <cstddef>` for `NULL`?

Comment: Yes, all files are saved. I've also included <cstddef> and still, the same error results.

Comment: @user1890265 can you try chopping off code to the minimum? What's the smallest sample that reproduces the error? What line is the error at?

Comment: Even this:

#include <cstddef>

#ifndef DOUBLY_LINKED_LIST

#define DOUBLY_LINKED_LIST

#endif

produces an error on the #ifndef line

Comment: @user1890265 post it on ideone.com formatted exactly as you have it. I'm afraid that what if you say is true, you might have a compiler bug on your hands.

Comment: I figured it out. ideone.com pinpointed the exact character causing the error -- the space on the #ifndef line (char 8). It seems as though that character was somehow corrupt, causing the error, so I deleted it and re-created a space. I feel like an idiot, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 #if !defined( _DOUBLY_LINKED_LIST_)
```

instead of

```
#ifdef _DOUBLY_LINKED_LIST_
```